# Out of Stack Space Error when setting Custom Object Parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom class module called Service with string parameters.
I instantiate the class by creating an object `this_service` like so:

```
Dim this_service As Service
Set this_service = New Service
```

Then I try to set a parameter to any string value like so:

```
this_service.Key = "HELLO"
```

When I run the macro I get the 28 Runtime Error, Out of Stack Space.

In my class module Service I have the following parameter definition and method calls:

```
Private pKey As String

Public Property Get Key() As String
    Key = pKey
End Property

Public Property Let Key(Value As String)
    Key = Value
End Property
```

I can't see any reason why I'd be getting this runtime error?

Comment: Probably a circular-reference type thing. Probably in `Key=Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Public Property Let` it should be:

`pKey = Value`

Right now it calls the setter recursively (indefinitely).